# Вывод сообщений, принадлежащих пользователю

Tags: jquery, mysql

Подскажите, как можно сделать вывод всех сообщений, принадлежащих пользователю на jQuery желательно с постоянным обновлением списка? Подкиньте пример, пожалуйста, или руководство. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вам надо использовать [.ajax()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81). В инете [найдёте массу примеров](http://bit.ly/OpjM1K). Вот, например, [первое, что попалось](http://codething.ru/ajax.php) на эту тему.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо,постараюсь разобраться,я как понимаю это можно использовать и для того что я написала в вопросе ?

Comment: Именно так. В общем-то, там всё предельно просто: ajax-ом отправляете запрос в файл-обработчик, там вытягиваете необходимое из БД и возвращаете ответ обратно в JS. Ответ обрабатывается и выводится пользователю на экран.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!Получила то что надо было узнать для решения проблемы.Попытаюсь обязательно разобраться.